# Practical interpersonal address exchange

Tags: address

How can addresses be exchanged practically & efficiently between two users?

Visually copying & keying them is impractical & faulty.

Comment: It would be neat to write a little program to encode them as English sentences or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very true! Manually copying a 34 character address is no fun.

You have three major options:

- [QR code.](http://bitcoinqrcode.org/) Print it out in advance.
- [Create a FirstBits address.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Firstbits)
- Bring your phone, and [load a client that supports NFC.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&hl=en)

By the way, if you enter someone's address wrong, the Bitcoins won't send - Bitcoin addresses have a checksum built in.

Comment: Concerning the checksum feature of addresses also see [What happens if I mistype the address when making a payment?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/194/5406).

Comment: Yes, QR codes with an integrated camera capture are sufficiently convenient.  Thank you