# What is the behavior of the try catch statement in lines 1707-1729 in the ui.cpp in the release 0.1?

Tags: protocol, payment, source-code

In the first public release, `ui.cpp` has this code on the lines in the subject:

```
void CSendingDialog::OnReply3(CDataStream& vRecv)
{
    int nRet;
    try
    {
        vRecv >> nRet;
        if (nRet > 0)
        {
            Error("The payment was sent, but the recipient was 
                unable to verify it.\n"
                "The transaction is recorded and will credit to 
                the recipient if it is valid,\n"
                "but without comment information.");
        return;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //// what do we want to do about this?
        Error("Payment was sent, but an invalid response was received");
        return;
}
```

The try catch statement at the bottom shows the error as payment sent but invalid response was received. In this case, does this mean that the send BTC would be lost forever [as in this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/194/what-happens-if-i-mistype-the-address-when-making-a-payment) or does this mean that the transaction would be part of some orphaned block ([like here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5859/what-are-orphaned-and-stale-blocks/5869#5869)).

Bonus, was something done to address the comment in the code?

Comment: Bitcoin originally had a "send to IP address" feature where you would connect to an IP address, ask them for a public key, and create a transaction using that public key as output.  This code is part of that feature.  This mechanism was eventually removed, so that's the eventual answer to "was something done".