# Bitcoins sent to wrong address

Tags: revert-transaction

I've make a mistake: unfortunately I've write my Bitcoin(s) from The Ledger to a wrong unknown adress. Is there any way to recover this mistake ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I mistype the address when making a payment?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/194/what-happens-if-i-mistype-the-address-when-making-a-payment)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get it back as you don't even know to whom the address belongs. Even if you knew the owner of the address it's his, her, etc. decision to transfer it back.

Answer (score 0):

Basically **no**. Because bitcoin is a **untrackable(?) and unrefundable** currency.

It's your luck if you get it back by finding the owner of the addr.**(literally impossible)** and requesting him to give your funds back.

**But** it's his decision also it's not illegal because it's your fault and he didn't do anything. Lets say it's illegal still there's a small chance that he'll get caught and you'll get your funds back because its untrackable(?).

Sorry for you.